# SQL rounding to decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I have a dataset which i need to do a calculation on price and round to decimal places. But the results aren't quite what is expected. The calculation is in the case statement

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Price DECIMAL(7,2) )

INSERT INTO #TEMP ( Price )
VALUES ( 119.99 )
        , ( 48.99 )

SELECT
    ID
    , Price
    , CASE WHEN Price > 10 THEN CONVERT( DECIMAL(7,2), Price * 1.08 - 0.05 ) END AS RRP
FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

with the results

```
ID  Price   RRP
1   119.99  129.54
2   48.99   52.86
```

I need to get the 129.54 to 129.55 and the 52.86 to 52.85 within the same case statement if that is possible to match up with another data set

Comment: `(119.99  * 1.08) - 0.05` = 129.5392, so 1.54 is correct.  Additionally,  ID 2 comes out to be 52.8592. What is the logic for you needing 129.55 and 52.85?

Comment: `round(price*1.08-0.05,2)` before the convert. otherwise the convert just truncates.  `THEN CONVERT( DECIMAL(7,2), round(price*1.08-0.05,2))`

Comment: PEMDAS issue? mixing multiplication and addition/subtraction in the wrong order can have different results - check out this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: @Eli I don't think it's PEMDAS. First result would be 123.59 if he intended for the subtraction to happening first.

Comment: The math results in: 129.5392 and 52.8592.  why is one being rounded up to 129.55 and the other rounded down to 52.85.  This isn't rounding.  So what is it?  I don't understand your rules.

Comment: @xQbert: Maybe rounding to the next `5`?

Comment: @dnoeth There are several countries that have abolished the penny... http://coincollectingenterprises.com/information/coin-eliminated-by-country/. That may be the case.

Comment: I'm with @xQbert. Your math is off or your results are wrong. 48.99 * 1.08 = 52.8592. Subtract .05 and you get 52.8592. Round and you get 52.86. Why would you expect 52.85 from this math?

Comment: `, CASE WHEN Price > 10 THEN CONVERT( DECIMAL(7,2), round((Price * 1.08 - 0.05)*20,0)/20) END AS RRP` maybe ... if rounding as @dnoeth suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you rounding to the nearest 5 cents because your country has gotten rid of the penny? This is the only logic that we can seem to follow with your expected results.

```
SELECT ID
    ,Price
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Price > 10
            THEN ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(7, 2), Price * 1.08 - 0.05) * 20, 0) / 20
        END AS RRP
FROM #Temp
```

Comment: I don't think I've seen comments deleted like this before.

Comment: @xQbert I haven't, either. I think we annoyed someone. Do we get a badge for that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to round to the nearest 5 cents or nearst 5 in 100ths decimal position.

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP ( Price )
VALUES ( 119.99 )
        , ( 48.99 )

SELECT
    ID
    , Price
    , Price * 1.08 - 0.05
    , CASE WHEN Price > 10 THEN CONVERT( DECIMAL(7,2), round((Price * 1.08 - 0.05)*20,0)/20) END AS RRP
FROM #Temp
```

DEMO:http://rextester.com/QIM12944